# Request Entity too large: Space push

Tags: python, push, pickle, streamlit

I trying to push my code in to `deta space` using space push but I get an error like this,

```
PS C:\Users\user1\game_rec> space push
Validating your Spacefile...

Your Spacefile looks good, proceeding with your push!

✓ Successfully started your build!
✓ Successfully pushed your Spacefile!
! Failed to push code: failed to push code, Request entity too large
Error: failed to push code, Request entity too large
```

Here is my file structure and their sizes.

```
game_rec
   |__.space (141 bytes)
   |__app.py (2 KB)
   |__requirements.txt
   |__games.pkl (1.80 MB)
   |__similarities.pkl (930 MB)
   |__.gitignore (1 KB)
   |__Spacefile (1 KB)
```

My spacefile look like this:

```
# Spacefile Docs: https://go.deta.dev/docs/spacefile/v0
v: 0
micros:
  - name: game_Rec
    src: .
    engine: python3.9
    run: streamlit run:app.py
```

I think `similarities.pkl` might be causing the problem due to its large size, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and found it we can use the `.spaceignore` file to ignore what we don't want to push to your space.

For the Details, check out the Doc: [The Space Runtime - Space Docs](https://deta.space/docs/en/build/fundamentals/the-space-runtime#ignoring-files-and-directories)